# Can I use Electron JS to convert my web app to DESKTOP app

Tags: mysql, ajax, datatable, electron

I have a web app developed using..(PHP,MYSQL,HTML,CSS,JS,AJAX,Datatables, bootstrapjs)

Now, I want to make a desktop version of the same app, and I came across electronjs.
The problem is I dont know whether ELECTRONJS will support all my requirements.

A breif of my requirements:
My app is responsive using datatables.net library including EDITOR for displaying the data .

the datatable plugin requires ajax calls to some API (Which I developed with PHP and hosted on a server)..

but now I want to even do all the DB Operations with electronjs so that my app can work offline.

I am not sure if I can do that with electron 
   - calling an API (created by same app) from HTML/frontJS
   - the API Returns Json data
   - the Front JS displays that data on front.

Kindly let me know if this can be done with electronjs,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically yes. You can build a desktop app like this.

But you wont be able to run it offline if it depends on a server sided API. If you can rewrite your backend Code in JavaScript and use a SQLite DB instead of a MySQL you can run this as electron App.
Keep in mind that your business logic in the frontend can always be abused because it’s not hidden from the user.

FYI: Electron only runs a browser inside it’s own App container. So there is actually no crucial difference between Browser or electron App.

Comment: will my Business logic be visible to the user even if I compile the code to create an electron executable ???

Comment: Not directly visible but you can only obfuscate Javascript. You can NOT compile Javascript. Even if you compile the whole App as .exe or .dmg you will still have plain or obfuscated JavaScript in it. So you will never have full security for it.